# mongo read from slave with primaryPreferred and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i've got a replica set on compose.io.
I've setted primaryPreferred on the config which is fine.

```
  { replset: { 
    rs_name: 'set-53453xxxxxxxxx', 
    strategy: 'ping', 
    read_secondary: true, 
    readPreference: 'primaryPreferred',
    slaveOk: true, 
    safe: true, 
    socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1 } 
  }}
```

But i'd like to read on secondary for background process such as stats.

should i open 2 connections ? one for primary, and one for slave ?
that's what i did. But when connecting on the slave i get a `not master and slaveOk=false` when querying.

i know that i can `rs.slaveOK()` on the mongo client to allow query but i need it in my app connection

this is how i init my slave connection:

```
var slaveCon = mongoose.createConnection()
slaveCon.open('slaveURL', { slaveOk: true }, callback)
// this give me the notMaster error when querying
```

any ideas ?